# How to stop running always unknown docker container

Tags: docker

Hello I'm on a PC that someone else used and when I run docker ps, there are a lot of containers listed.
I tried to stop all of them using :

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

but they are recreated automatically.
Can someone help because the PC is really slow ?

Comment: Maybe stop docker service : sudo systemctl stop docker

Comment: you have to use `docker update --restart=no container_name` . because those might be having restart policy.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque good idea if i don't want to use docker but i do need it

Comment: Yes or you can do docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq) to force rm on container that are restarted

Comment: @HirenNamera no effect

Comment: the rm -f is ineffective as well

Comment: then remove images also. If possible remove images .